# display image with help of mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image

i have my sql database with table content as [image varchar(22)]
stored the value of image as url location of image as images/tree.jpg

how to retrive it with php

```
<?php
    $link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("bookstore");
    $qry="select * from books where btype='$cat'";
    $res=mysql_query($qry,$link);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res));
    {

        print " <img src=http://localhost/zack/PROJECT/".$row['image'] ." width=323px >";

    }
?>
```

Comment: What about the code you show doesn't work?

Comment: What is the question? What is not working? What is the expected/actual result?

Comment: Just noticed, your image src isn't wrapped in quotes. Still don't know specifically what the problem is, but that doesn't look right.

Comment: Any new projects should be using `mysqli` or PDO and **NEVER** `mysql_query`. It is not safe unless used very carefully. [Escape your SQL properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you may have serious problems with your code. It looks like you're using very bad reference material so you should try using a framework that provides a lot of database services for you, like [CodeIgnighter](http://codeigniter.com/), which will provide a foundation for applications like this, much easier than starting from scratch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That should work if SELECT statement is correct and image realy resides in /zack/PROJECT subfolder of your web root folder.

```
<?php
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("bookstore");
$qry="SELECT image FROM books WHERE btype='$cat'";
$res=mysql_query($qry,$link);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res));
{
    echo '<img src="http://localhost/zack/PROJECT/'.$row['image'] .'" width="323" >';
}
?>
```

Comment: **DO NOT USE** `mysql_query` even in trivial examples. It is extremely dangerous and very difficult to use properly. Use `mysqli` or PDO and [escape your SQL properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This example contains a potentially career-terminating bug in it.

Comment: what exactly is wrong with mysql_query?

Comment: for($i=0;$i<mysql_numrows($res);$i++)   worked by using this there is some problem in while loop ... thx sbrbot for correcting indentations

Comment: This is weird situation, I answered your question and my answer was accepted as correct solution but I have negative score for it!